Imagemagick convert -thumbnail with out of bounds selected frame produces unwanted files
I'm new to imagemagick, my goal is to make a thumbnail from an image or a video with the selected frame. If I request an out of bounds frame, I'm expecting the command to fail and to not produce output files.
The problem is that in case of out of bounds selected frame, 1 thumbnail seems to be produced for each frame in the file. If I were to run this on a big video file, it could be problematic.
convert version: 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25
I created a gif file with 2 frames, animated at 1 fps.
The following commands give me the 1st and 2nd frames in output.png which is what I expected.
convert -thumbnail input.gif[0] output.png
convert -thumbnail input.gif[1] output.png

When using an out of bounds frame, the command produces an unwanted result.
convert -thumbnail input.gif[2] output.png # input_gif[10] gives same result

This produces the files: output-0.png and output-1.png
This exits with an exit code 1 and displays the following message:
convert-im6.q16: InvalidImageIndex 'input.gif' @ error/list.c/CloneImages/294

Is it a bug ? Is there a way to tell convert to do nothing when the selected frame is wrong (I haven't found such a flag for the moment) ?

You could make a post to the Imagemagick GIT forum at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6.  Alternately, you could check the number of frames first and limit your command. See %n at https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php. convert input.gif -format "%n/n" info: | head -n 1.  The pipe to head is to limit the results to just the first time it lists the number of frames, otherwise, you get the number of frames for every frame in the image.

Thanks. Your alternative is my last resort solution, I would prefer the command to stop on warning/error instead of producing invalid result.

Just created a post on their forum, thanks for the convert lena.jpg zelda1.jpg -loop 0 -set delay 50 x.gif command it's perfect for "steps to reproduce" sections.

It is not a bug. My version of IM does not give the two output results for out of bounds frame selection and gives a proper error message.  So you need to upgrade your IM version to a current version that has that apparently fixed.

@fmw42 I saw your 2 comments, thanks for your help, I had understood, there is no misunderstanding. Here is the github issue https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6/issues/332 I created this morning. My IM versions come from the official ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 (in docker) apt repositories. I will look to upgrade the version from sources or other recommended way if the github issue doesn't give another solution.

Have you considered installing the "magick" portable version of the current IM. See https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

I installed from sources in a dockerfile, built 6 and 7 last versions. The bug doesn't occur anymore with the 7 with magickdirectly, but the render doesn't correspond to what I would expect. I made some tests, rendering a single frame with ffmpeg and creating the thumbnail with magick produces the result I want with .gif and .mp4 files.

What are your exact versions of IM 7.x.x.x.  Use ``magick -version to find it.

I forced it to 7.1.1-36 in the dockerfile, the command magick -version confirms it

I am on IM 6.9.13.13 on Mac OSX Ventura and don't have that problem.
convert lena.jpg zelda1.jpg -loop 0 -set delay 50 x.gif

identify x.gif
x.gif[0] GIF 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 0.000u 0:00.002
x.gif[1] GIF 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 97232B 0.000u 0:00.001

convert x.gif[3] x.jpg
convert: invalid image index `x.gif' @ error/list.c/CloneImages/296.

Proper IM syntax would read the input before any settings or operators (such as -thumbnail), and finally the output.
I am not sure if that will make a difference on IM 6 (it would on IM 7), but try that.

Tried with ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 last imagemagick from apt (version 6.9.12-98), but still getting the same error. Your command produces the same error (2 output files).

But on my system, I do not get the two frames output with convert x.gif[3] x.jpg

What are your exact versions of IM 7.x.x.x.  Use ``magick -version to find it.
